# Why won't R nest my factors?

Tags: r, nested, anova

I am trying to run a nested ANOVA in R, but R keeps returning results with many more df than my model should have. It seems like it is failing to nest my factors as I have specified.

My models are:

```
 mod1<-(lm(response ~ factor3/factor2/factor1, data=data))
```

Where factor3 is nested within factor2 and factor2 is nested within factor1. I have also tried:

```
mod2<- (lm(response ~ factor1/factor2/factor3, data=data))
```

Reproducible example:

```
dput(data)
structure(list(factor2 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L), factor3 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label =     c("flower", 
"leaf", "pollen", "stem"), class = "factor"), factor1 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,      
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label =     c("BDY", 
"ELK", "FOO", "GTH"), class = "factor"), response = c(6681.23, 
14244.08, 12968.21, 12010.11, 23068.28, 9814.8, 7330.3, 8668.38, 
11268.32, 15847.31, 14477.16, 11777.99, 18114.18, 7243.96, 15818.11, 
14688.62, 16494.26, 20607.73, 12091.07, 16520.8, 23774.68, 18982.81, 
28254.47, 22195.51, 15789.27, 18935.79, 25432.66, 26710.84, 8251.26, 
21494.77, 4156.25, 9034.05, 14997.58, 9326.1, 7107.22, 7242.1, 
5918.55, 13406.13, 10943.45, 14467.25, 5537.86, 3633.19, 15885.53, 
15347.71, 17762.4, 19459.68, 11572.8, 12734.17, 14007.17, 12903.34, 
20022.23, 22562.52, 24866.6, 17669.95, 23224.24, 24176.56, 504.47, 
1091, 5536.14, 2013.21, 4784.39, 3467.77, 1891.02, 3648.9, 1781.21, 
1738.36, 1136, 999.91, 8317.76, 1316.81, 2247.32, 11255.5, 3226.06, 
2934.25, 1431.31, 5799.91, 1977.36, 2284.3, 1358.63, 275.32, 
1676.3, 1367.51, 1642.89, 3845.59, 13514.46, 8301.19, 11401.89, 
12266.25, 5522.93, 6129.18, 5214.82, 3267.63, 6775.97, 7890.34, 
5551.34, 2895.41, 4856.73, 6811.57, 8068.19, 6628.74, 5960.92, 
7924.07, 5158.48, 4689.99, 9125.87, 9459.41, 12376.81, 9544.07, 
9357.06, 12328.59, 21184.79)), .Names = c("factor2", "factor3", 
"factor1", "response"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-111L))
```

As you can see, there are only 28 replicates, from which 4 measurements were taken. However, when I run:

```
mod1<-(lm(response ~ factor1/factor2/factor3, data=data))
anova(mod1)   

> anova(mod1)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: response
                        Df     Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
factor1                  3  724275464 241425155 16.2257 1.577e-08 ***
factor1:factor2          4   24834710   6208678  0.4173    0.7958    
factor1:factor2:factor3 12 3434955912 286246326 19.2381 < 2.2e-16 ***
Residuals               91 1354003526  14879160                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

or

```
mod2<-(lm(response ~ factor3/factor2/factor1, data=data))
anova(mod2)

> anova(mod2)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: response
                        Df     Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
factor3                  3 2938598064 979532688 71.5319 < 2.2e-16 ***
factor3:factor2          4  926343993 231585998 16.9119  2.12e-10 ***
factor3:factor2:factor1 12  427005751  35583813  2.5986  0.005113 ** 
Residuals               91 1246121804  13693646                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I get 91 residual df.

My question is: What is wrong with my data organization and/or my model specification, and how can I fix them/it?

Comment: Thank you @useR. Factor3 (tissue type) needs to be nested within factor 2 (individual) and factor 2 needs to be nested within factor 3 (sampling location). I am expecting residual df < 28

Comment: @useR Factor 3 is a vector of measurements of the response from different tissues, there is one measurement per tissue per individual (factor 2), individuals each came from one of 4 sites (factor 1). If the data don't reflect this nesting structure- then it seems like at least part of the answer is that I organized the data incorrectly, but I don't know how to check this or fix it.

Comment: So, factor2 has 1:28 because there are 28 individuals, each of which contributed 1 measurement each from 1 of 4 separate tissues (factor3). So each of the 111 observations of factor3 should be nested within one of the 28 levels of factor2. Those 28 levels (individuals) should be subsequently nested within one of 4 levels of factor 1 (locations that the individuals came from).

Comment: I think `factor2` and `factor3` are _crossed_ because every combination of `factor2` and `factor3` are present. `factor2` is _nested_ within `factor1` because each individual only comes from one location. See [Here](http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/the-difference-between-crossed-and-nested-factors/) for explanation. I think this is why you don't get the expected residual df, because not all your `factors` are nested within each other

Comment: @useR Ah, ok, that makes a lot of sense. Is there a way to specify a combination of crossed and nested factors in R without resorting to a mixed model approach?